# How do I hide menu based the localStorage in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

How do I hide certain menu based on the localStorage value that have been assigned for the user,
example of menu that I have.

```
Sale
-----
--> Profit
--> Commission
--> Loss
--> Monthly Report
--> Yearly Report
```

Only user with `type_user == 2` can view this menu

```
Sale
----
--> Monthly Report
--> Yearly Report
```

and
`type_user == 1` can view this menu

```
Sale
-----
--> Profit
--> Commission
--> Loss
```

This is the code that I have tried but unfortunately I don't get any output based on my code. How do I fix this code in order to display the menu based on their `type_user`?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Title of the document</title>

<script>
        let user_type = localStorage.getItem('user_type');

        let user = ``;
        if(user_type == 2){
            
            user += `<li class="nk-menu-item">
                            <a href="monthly_report" class="nk-menu-link">
                                <span class="nk-menu-icon"><em class="icon ni ni-plus"></em></span>
                                <span class="nk-menu-text"> Monthly Report</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nk-menu-item">
                            <a href="yearly_report" class="nk-menu-link">
                                <span class="nk-menu-icon"><em class="icon ni ni-file-text"></em></span>
                                <span class="nk-menu-text">Yearly Report</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>`;

        }
        else if (user_type == 1){

            user += `<li class="nk-menu-item">
                            <a href="profit" class="nk-menu-link">
                                <span class="nk-menu-icon"><em class="icon ni ni-file-text"></em></span>
                                <span class="nk-menu-text">Profit</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nk-menu-item">
                            <a href="commission" class="nk-menu-link">
                                <span class="nk-menu-icon"><em class="icon ni ni-file-text"></em></span>
                                <span class="nk-menu-text">Commission</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nk-menu-item">
                            <a href="loss" class="nk-menu-link">
                                <span class="nk-menu-icon"><em class="icon ni ni-file-text"></em></span>
                                <span class="nk-menu-text">Loss</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>`;

        }
</script>

</head>

<body>
<div class="nk-content ">
    <div class="container wide-xl">
        <div class="nk-content-inner">
<ul>
          <li class="nk-menu-heading">
            <h6 class="overline-title">Sale</h6>
          </li>
           
           //how do I call it here in the ${user}
</ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Why are you using `$(document).ready` if your not using any other jquery code?

Comment: You’re close. See the [jQuery DOM manipulation documentation](//api.jquery.com/category/manipulation) to insert `user` at the correct point.

Comment: FYI: Scripts are not supposed to go before the `<html>` tag. Add them to the `<head>` or `<body>` tag

Comment: You try to use `<li>` but where you open `<ul>` ? How you suppose script paste the html into div if you not write the line of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i did?

- Insert an `<ul>` for containe `<li>`
- user `innerHTML` for paste the menu into `<ul>`
- add `addEventListener` instead of `$(document).ready` ([You might not need jQuery](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/))
- add `parseInt` for the `localStorage`

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const menu = document.querySelector('.nk-menu-heading');
  //let user_type = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('user_type'));
  let user_type = 1;
  let user = ``;
  if (user_type === 2) {

    user += `<li class="nk-menu-item">
                            <a href="monthly_report" class="nk-menu-link">
                                <span class="nk-menu-icon"><em class="icon ni ni-plus"></em></span>
                                <span class="nk-menu-text"> Monthly Report</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nk-menu-item">
                            <a href="yearly_report" class="nk-menu-link">
                                <span class="nk-menu-icon"><em class="icon ni ni-file-text"></em></span>
                                <span class="nk-menu-text">Yearly Report</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>`;

  } else if (user_type === 1) {

    user += `<li class="nk-menu-item">
                            <a href="profit" class="nk-menu-link">
                                <span class="nk-menu-icon"><em class="icon ni ni-file-text"></em></span>
                                <span class="nk-menu-text">Profit</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nk-menu-item">
                            <a href="commission" class="nk-menu-link">
                                <span class="nk-menu-icon"><em class="icon ni ni-file-text"></em></span>
                                <span class="nk-menu-text">Commission</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nk-menu-item">
                            <a href="loss" class="nk-menu-link">
                                <span class="nk-menu-icon"><em class="icon ni ni-file-text"></em></span>
                                <span class="nk-menu-text">Loss</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>`;

  }
  menu.innerHTML = user;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nk-content ">
  <div class="container wide-xl">
    <div class="nk-content-inner">
      <h6 class="overline-title">Sale</h6>
      <ul class="nk-menu-heading">

      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

PS: i don't use `localStorage` because into snippet doesn't work.